# What does a servlet container do if a servlet does nothing?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jboss, httpresponse

I'm running a Java webapp on a servlet container (Jboss, Tomcat, Jetty...). I know that every servlet (or filter) that I create starts with a request and response object. This implies that the servlet container has already created some kind of default response to use even though my servlet hasn't done anything. I'm curious as to what this response contains. Imagine the fictional case where my servlet or filters do absolutely nothing and return nothing. What will my client (browser) see?

- What is the status code of the response? I would expect 204 (no response)
- Is the content-length attribute set to 0?
- are there any other special headers related to this "empty" response set to a value?

I can't seems to find info about this in the documentation of servlet containers because it's (obviously) not very useful.

Comment: You'll get a response body of length `0`, headers set will depend on your container, however the status code will be the default... which is `200 (ok)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if your servlet doesn't do anything..means it has nothing in the service() method...then also the servlet container will do its job ..i.e

- load the servlet class
- instantiate the class
- initialize the servlet
- service the threads.. (Even though it has nothing to do..200 OK and response body of length 0)
- destroys the thread.

Comment: There is a 200 OK response. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.